# How to save a logo as SVG format for web use?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a logo that I designed in illustrator, I want to save it as an SVG for a web designer friend, I am very new to saving in SVG formats, so I really don't know the options I should choose.
I have a CC 2014 Version, so that article "http://creativedroplets.com/export-svg-for-the-web-with-illustrator-cc/"
mentions that I should choose these to make it ready for web design. I don't get why we should choose "only glyphs used", I created outlines for fonts, expanded strokes and everything looks good now. those are the options article mentioned.

[image: svg options]

I don't really know what's best for web design, your answers will be appreciated!

Comment: You should update Illustrator and use [export](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html) instead of save. About export [options](https://webdogs.com/blog/export-svg-web-using-adobe-illustrator/)

Comment: But i can't update it for now. what should be the options for CC Version?

Comment: Then you can use the settings recommended in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236365/optimal-settings-for-exporting-svgs-for-the-web-from-illustrator)